# The existence of left-hand limits for a strictly increasing function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

My question is : "Assume $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, and $f$ is strictly increasing; that is, $f(a) < f(b)$ whenever $a<b$. Show that for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$, $\lim_{x \to c^{-}} f(x)$ exists.
" I attempt to construct two increasing sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ both approach to the same $c$, and then I argue that limit of  $f(x_n) = f(y_n)$ by using contradiction argument. Any other approach or problems with my sketch-proof?

Comment: Your idea is fine, but it would help if you can show some details to see whether your intended implementation of it is accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\xi_c = \sup \{ f(x) \mid x < c \}$ exists. Show that $\lim_{x\to c-} f(x) = \xi_c$.

By the way, it suffices to assume that $f$ is increasing ($f(a) \le f(b)$ whenever $a \le b$).

Answer (score 1):

A different  method. Let $(x_n)_n$ and $(y_n)_n$ be strictly increasing sequences, each converging to $c.$ Since $(f(x_n))_n$ and $(f(y_n))_n$ are increasing and each is bounded above by $f(c),$ the limits $X=\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_n)$ and $Y=\lim_{n\to \infty}f(y_n)$ exist.

Consider the set $A=\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}\cup \{y_n:n\in \Bbb N\}.$ We can enumerate $A=\{a_n: n\in \Bbb N\}$ with $a_n<a_{n+1}$ for each $n$ because (i) each of $\{x_n:n\in \Bbb N\}$ and $\{y_n: n\in \Bbb N\}$ is countably infinite, so $A$ is countably infinite, and (ii) $A\subset (-\infty,c)$ and for any $r<c$ the set $\{a\in A:a<r\}$ is finite.

Now the sequence $(f(a_n))_n$ is increasing and bounded above by $f(c)$ so it has a limit $L.$ Any sub-sequence of a convergent sequence converges to the same limit. Both $(f(x_n))_n$ and $(f(y_n))_n$ are sub-sequences of $(f(a_n))_n,$ so $X=L$ and $Y=L.$

It is sufficient that $f$ is increasing but not necessarily strictly increasing. BTW, for $n\in \Bbb N$ there is a unique $g(n)$ such that $x_n=a_{g(n)},$ and $g:\Bbb N\to \Bbb N$ is strictly increasing. So $(f(x_n))_n=(f(a_{g(n)}))_n$ is a sub-sequence of $(f(a_n))_n.$ And similarly so is $(f(y_n))_n.$